# EPPlus 6.x - Show/Hide Pivot Table Field List (hidePivotFieldList="1")

Tags: pivot-table, ms-office, openxml, epplus

**EPPlus version: 6.1.0, .NET Core 7, C#**

Is there a way to hide the Pivot Table Field List? I couldn't find any existing methods to accomplish this.

[image: Pivot Table Context Menu] [image: PivotTable Analyze Menu]

I have added a Macro to accomplish this behaviour, however the user experience is poor as they have to enable macros.

I have examined the generated workbook.xml file before and after hiding the Field List, it appears to add the following xml element / attribute :

```
<workbookPr hidePivotFieldList="1" defaultThemeVersion="166925"/>
```

I was expecting a method similar to **WorkBook.hidePivotFieldList()**

It looks like XmlDocument.WorkbookXml is read only, perhaps there are methods to manipulate the generated workbook.xml file, so I can add the  element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to prepend the missing  XML Element to the ExcelPackage.Workbook.WorkbookXml

```
XmlDocument xdoc = package.Workbook.WorkbookXml;
XmlNode newStateNode = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("workbook")[0];         
XmlElement XEle = xdoc.CreateElement("workbookPr", newStateNode.NamespaceURI);
XEle.SetAttribute("hidePivotFieldList", "1");
xdoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(XEle.Clone());
```